# Programa em c apresentando saida, estranha diferente do valor das variaveis

Tags: c, struct, ide, codeblocks

Eu estou com um problema na execução de um program em e c que quando eu o compilo e executo ele me mostra um valor que não esta definido em minha variavel eu estou achando que é algum bug com a ide ou algo relacionado ao buffer vou deixar um screenshot para vocês verem

o codigo:

[image: struct c erro printf variavel]

a saida:

[image: saida extranha codigo c]

Comment: Posta o código  e  a saída, não imagens

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Este erro ocorre pois, você que usar uma string(texto) e usou apenas um char(caractere). Na linguagem C uma string é representada por um vetor de caracteres terminado com caractere nulo '\0'. Porém você colocou apenas como **char nick**. O correto seria por exemplo **char nick[100];**

Ao declarar char o compilador vai alocar apenas 1byte de memória capaz de armazenar um caractere.

[image: char ao inves de string]

Contudo após colocar este char[100] você irá receber outro erro, confira:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Ou seja, não é possivel atribuir a um campo de string de uma struct para uma constante string "Assanges".
Para funcionar você deve utilizar a função de  (string copy) ou 
**strcpy(destino, origem).** 
Assim coloque: strcpy(user.nick, "Assanges"); e vai funcionar!

Lembre de fazer include de string.h

Confira:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Veja abaixo o código correto

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct User{
 char nick[100];
 int id;
}user;
int main(){
   strcpy(user.nick, "Assanges");
   user.id = 45474;
   printf("\nNick:%s\nId:%d \n", user.nick, user.id);

return 0;
}
```

Agora ao executar dará certo!

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Legal uma resposta bem explicada, a única ressalva é o uso de imagens em vez de texto. Seria melhor copiar e colar os códigos (basta marcar com o mouse e clicar no botão `{ }` da barra de formatação, ou apertar control-k para formatar como código. Em texto qualquer usuário pode copiar e testar a solução sem ter que redigitar tudo. Além disso, imagens geram um problema sério com acessibilidade e leitura em dispositivos pequenos.

Comment: Obrigado pelo feedback! Gostei! Irei fazer isso nas futuras respostas! Abraço